# How to compile cap-ng on Impish?

Tags: package-management, compiling, 21.10

I'm on `Impish`, and have installed the latest version of `libcap-ng-dev`,
Compiling with `gcc 11.2`, via `Visual Studio Remote Linux`

The following program cannot be statically linked

```
#include <cap-ng.h>

int main()
{
    capng_have_capability(0, 0);
}
```

Here is the build output:

```
1>/usr/bin/ld : error : really/long/path/main.o: in function `main':
1>main.c : error : (.text.startup+0xd): undefined reference to `capng_have_capability'
1>collect2 : error : ld returned 1 exit status

Here are the linker flags:

-o"really/long/path/out" "3600000" -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,--no-undefined "g++ -static" -l"cap" -l"audit" -Wl,-L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -Wl,-z,now
```

Adding `-lcap` does not change the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, I just needed to add `-lcap-ng`.